# Unsupported shader model specified "fx_4_0_level_9_3"

Tags: c++, direct3d

I'm making a 3d game engine and after I added shaders this comes up in the compiler:
Unsupported shader model specified "fx_4_0_level_9_3", I'm using d3d11 to make this engine btw
Here's the code:

```
bool GraphicsEngine::createShaders()
{
    ID3DBlob* errblob = nullptr;
    D3DCompileFromFile(L"shader.fx", nullptr, nullptr, "vsmain", "vs_5_0", NULL, NULL, 
    &m_vsblob, 
    &errblob);
    D3DCompileFromFile(L"shader.fx", nullptr, nullptr, "psmain", "ps_5_0", NULL, NULL, 
    &m_psblob, 
    &errblob);
    m_d3d_device->CreateVertexShader(m_vsblob->GetBufferPointer(), m_vsblob->GetBufferSize(), 
    nullptr, &m_vs);
    m_d3d_device->CreatePixelShader(m_psblob->GetBufferPointer(), m_psblob->GetBufferSize(), 
    nullptr, &m_ps);
    return true;

}


bool GraphicsEngine::setShaders()
{
    m_imm_context->VSSetShader(m_vs, nullptr, 0);
    m_imm_context->PSSetShader(m_ps, nullptr, 0);
    return true;
}

void GraphicsEngine::getShaderBufferAndSize(void** bytecode, UINT* size)
{
    *bytecode = this->m_vsblob->GetBufferPointer();
    *size = (UINT)this->m_vsblob->GetBufferSize();

}
```

Comment: AFAIK effect files are no longer supported in Direct3D 11 and above. I don't do Direct3D programming anymore but your shader should be specific to either vertex shader for compiling vertex shader, likewise the same applies to pixel shader too

Comment: Please add the content of ``shader.fx`` to the question.

Comment: I fixed it I just needed to exclude the shader.fx from the compiling process